# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in <!DOCTYPE html>

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

i am sending a ajax request to external domain. Here is my code,
There might be an issue on JSONP response while converting the html data to jsonp. I have tried so many solution because i am requesting to cross domain so i have to use JSONP else i have to face cross domain error. Error when Use simple JSON ERROR: " XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.blink.com.kw/search-result.aspx?text=apple&searchfor=all. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'localhost:49324' is therefore not allowed access."

Response error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#bt").click(function(){
       $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://www.blink.com.kw/search-result.aspx?text=apple&searchfor=all',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {          
        console.log(data);
//$("#data").html(data);
        }
        }); 
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your url does not return any `json` with `padding` == `JSONP`

Answer (score 2):

This is probably happening because you are specifying it as JSONP, which executes the data as a script in order to execute a callback function.  If it sends back a normal HTML document with the doctype being the first line it sees, this would occur.

Comment: please read full description of question, when i use simple json, its shows cross domain error. :(

Comment: That is normal.  JSON downloads it using a standard XMLHttpRequest, which is expected to follow the same-origin policy.  Specifying it as JSONP creates a script tag with the URL as the source, expecting it to execute a callback function defined elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this code, basically we should not use url like this.
>   Also, this url is not return any json or jsonp format, please check your link as well

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#bt").click(function(){
       $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://www.blink.com.kw/search-result.aspx',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data:{
            text: apple,
            searchfor: all
        }
        success: function (data) {          
        console.log(data);
        }
        }); 
    });
});
</script>
```

Hope this helps :)